# overlay points over polygons in R

Tags: r, r-sp

I need to overlay 40,000 points over 100,000 polygons. The polygons were created using:

```
polygon <- gBuffer(pc, width=500, byid=TRUE)
```

The overlay was created using:

```
test <- over(pts, polygon)
```

So as a result, I have a data frame with the attributes of the points falling in each polygon (mean). My question is is it possible to cbind() the gps coordinates (centroid) of the polygon to my data frame?

I have looked on google and stackoverflow but I did not find anything on that subject.The solution is probably easy but I just can't see it :)

Any help would be appreciated!

thank you
Martin

**Edit**:
So what if I want to select polygons that
have (one or more) points in them. I used

```
test <- over(polygons, pts, returnList = TRUE)
```

How can I get the coordinates of the polygon bind to the list of data frame (each corresponding to a polygon). I need the info. as a list because I need to calculate distance driven.
thanks
M.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, `test` is not a `data.frame` but a vector with the polygon index for each point in `pts`. Try

```
pts$polygon_id = over(pts, polygon)
```

this promotes `pts` from a `SpatialPoints` object to a `SpatialPointsDataFrame`.